# How to use buttons in java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am new to programming just picked up for the last six months and have been on and off. My question is how do I get my button to take me to my next panel to show my game panel from my main panel. I have a switch case which should check for my value of my button which I set to start when clicked. But for some reason I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.

I am at lost and just need some help really picking up on my mistake that I am making and how to improve. Each of these class are different files.

```
// Just to start game and nothing else
public class Starter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Window window = new Window();
        window.createWindow();
    }
}

// Has values that can be used for all classes
public class Common
{
    int width, height;
    Font titleFont;
    Font normalFont;
    Color white;
    Color black;
    
    public Common()
    {
        width = 800;
        height = 600;
        titleFont = new Font("Time New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 90);
        normalFont = new Font("Time New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 26);
        white = Color.white;
        black = Color.black;
    }
}

//Class to create just Frame and add to frame
public class Window
{
    JFrame window;
    String title;
    MainPanel mainPanel;
    Common values;
    
    public Window()
    {
        window = new JFrame();
        title = "Game";
        mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        values = new Common();
    }
    
    public void createWindow()
    {
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setSize(values.width, values.height);
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        window.add(mainPanel.mainPanel());
        mainPanel.createMainPanel();
        
        window.setVisible(true);    
    }
}

//Main Menu Panel
public class MainPanel
{
    JPanel mainPanel;
    Common values;
    JButton startButton;
    JLabel titleLabel;
    Manager manager;
    
    public MainPanel()
    {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        values = new Common();
        startButton = new JButton();
        titleLabel = new JLabel();
        manager = new Manager();
    }
    
    public void createMainPanel()
    {
        mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, values.width, values.height);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        startButton.setText("Start");
        startButton.setBounds(350, 400, 100, 50);
        startButton.setFocusable(false);
        startButton.setBackground(values.black);
        startButton.setForeground(values.white);
        startButton.setFont(values.normalFont);
        startButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        startButton.addActionListener(manager);
        startButton.setActionCommand("Start");
        
        titleLabel.setText("Solo Level");
        titleLabel.setBounds(200, 100, 600, 100);
        titleLabel.setFont(values.titleFont);
        titleLabel.setForeground(values.white);
        titleLabel.setBackground(values.black);
        
        //Add everything to Main Panel
        mainPanel.add(titleLabel);
        mainPanel.add(startButton);
    }
    
    public JPanel mainPanel()
    {
        return mainPanel;
    }
}

// Class to control buttons and change panels
public class Manager implements ActionListener
{
    String choice;
    MainPanel mp;
    GamePanel gp;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        choice = e.getActionCommand();
        
        switch(choice)
        {
            case "Start" :
                changeMainPanel();
                break;
            case "next" : 
                break;
            case "left" : 
                break;
            case "right" :
                break;
        } 
    }
    
    public void changeMainPanel()
    {
        mp.mainPanel.setVisible(false);
        gp.gamePanel.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// Game Panel not working
public class GamePanel
{
    JPanel gamePanel;
    Common values;
    JLabel test;
    
    public GamePanel()
    {
        gamePanel = new JPanel();
        values = new Common();
        test = new JLabel();
    }
    
    public void createGamePanel()
    {
        gamePanel.setBounds(0, 0, values.width, values.height);
        test.setText("This is a test");
        test.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 250);
        gamePanel.add(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 2) Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for working examples to get you started.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I think it would be usefull to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example